# Azure Remote Debugging API App slot

Tags: visual-studio, azure, remote-debugging, azure-api-apps

I am unable to start the remote debugger **on a specific slot**, instead it keeps attaching to production. No errors.

For the sake of my question I’ll refer to the API app name as “myapi” and I’m using VS2015.

Here are the steps I took:

1. I created an App Service for API (API App), which I intend to use as production.
   i.e. myapi.azurewebsites.net
2. Added a DEV slot, which automatically created the link myapi-dev.azurewebsites.net
3. Downloaded publish profile for the **DEV slot**
4. Imported the profile to the Visual Studio project and published.
5. Did a “SWAP” (between PROD and DEV)
6. Did another publish to DEV, because it became empty after the swap
7. At this point both DEV and PROD are working normally as API.  -  So far so good.
8. Turned on “Remote Debugging” for the DEV slot and for the main (PROD)
9. In the Visual Studio Cloud explorer, I right click on the main “myapi” node (which I use as PROD) and click “Attach Debugger”. 
   It opens the API page in the browser with the production address and debugging works great - so far behavior as expected.
10. I expand the node and expand “Deployment Slots”, **right click on the DEV slot** which is “myapi(dev)” and click “Attach Debugger”.
    it **opens the browser with the production address** and the debugger does work, but on the production, not the dev slot as I intended.  – Unexpected behavior.

Troubleshooting:

11. In the cloud explorer, when right clicking on the DEV slot and clicking “Open in Browser” it does open the DEV address, as expected. But for some reason when clicking “Attach Debugger” it opens the browser in PROD address. - Unexpected behaviour.
12. Created DEV2 slot, deployed to it, confirmed it’s working. Attempted to “Attach Debugger” on DEV2 slot, but again it attaches on PROD. – Unexpected behavior.
13. In App Services I created completely new API app and a DEV slot for that app, Attempted to “Attach Debugger”, but again it attaches on PROD. – Unexpected behavior.
14. Attempted from a colleagues computer, same issue.

No Errors at any point.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a similar scenario.
1. Created Staging slot and the default production slot of a web app.
2. Published the debug version of my app to prod. And also debug version to the Staging slot.
3. Attached the debugger to the staging slot from visual studio 2017 cloud explorer.
4. Browsed the staging website. The break point was hit.
5. Attached the  debugger to the default(production slot) from visual studio 2017 cloud explorer.
6. Browsed the production site. The break point was hit.

I see two things different in my case the visual studio 2017 and  publishing the debug configuration of the code to both the slots.

Comment: Avanish ! thank you for simulating !
I also published the debug to both slots. 
But yours is a web app, and mine is api app. shouldn't be a difference thought. Do you suspect the issue might be VS 2015  ?

Comment: Might be worth giving a shot